# 2001 F150 4.2 V6 knocking noise

Tags: ford, noise, f-150, engine-knock

[image]
I have a loud knocking noise in my engine. It stopped for awhile but is back. I just replaced the heads and all gaskets, due to overheating. Now have it back together and it's knocking still. It keeps Pace with the rmp at the time. It's loud. Hoping it's lifters and not rod.

Comment: Oh and it only has 86,000 original milea

Answer (score 0):

Is the knocking noise from the top or bottom of the engine, front or rear? if you have not checked it yet, could possibly be from the timing belt/chain. also may be faulty hydraulic lifter, they can make a decent amount of noise